# jqgrid: how to fix paging after filtering?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

I have an index as an extra searching option for my jqGrid:

```
<a class="letter" href="javascript:void">C</a>


 $(".letter").click(
        function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var letter = this.innerHTML;
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Products")',
                type:'POST',
                data: '_search=true&nd=1345531875941&rows=5&page=1&sidx=ProductID&sord=asc&filters=%7B%22groupOp%22%3A%22AND%22%2C%22rules%22%3A%5B%7B%22field%22%3A%22ProductName%22%2C%22op%22%3A%22bw%22%2C%22data%22%3A%22'+letter+ '%22%7D%5D%7D&searchField=&searchString=&searchOper=',
                success: function(data){
                    jQuery("#jqgProducts")[0].addJSONData(data);
            }
            });
        });
```

The data retrieved is fine (rows starting with 'C'), the pager shows : 'page 1 of 2'. However when I want to go to the second page it does  not display the right data( Which would be the other Names that start with 'C'). How can I make the page display the right data?

Answer (score 0):

```
data: '_search=true&nd=1345531875941&rows=5&page=1&sidx=ProductID&sord=asc&filters=%7B%22groupOp%22%3A%22AND%22%2C%22rules%22%3A%5B%7B%22field%22%3A%22ProductName%22%2C%22op%22%3A%22bw%22%2C%22data%22%3A%22'+letter+ '%22%7D%5D%7D&searchField=&searchString=&searchOper='
```

dynamically pass the parameter test "page=1" to "page=2" or manually for testing purposes

Manually:

```
data: '_search=true&nd=1345531875941&rows=5&page=2&sidx=ProductID&sord=asc&filters=%7B%22groupOp%22%3A%22AND%22%2C%22rules%22%3A%5B%7B%22field%22%3A%22ProductName%22%2C%22op%22%3A%22bw%22%2C%22data%22%3A%22'+letter+ '%22%7D%5D%7D&searchField=&searchString=&searchOper='
```

Dynamically:

```
data: '_search=true&nd=1345531875941&rows=5&page='+anyPage+'&sidx=ProductID&sord=asc&filters=%7B%22groupOp%22%3A%22AND%22%2C%22rules%22%3A%5B%7B%22field%22%3A%22ProductName%22%2C%22op%22%3A%22bw%22%2C%22data%22%3A%22'+letter+ '%22%7D%5D%7D&searchField=&searchString=&searchOper='
```